# Creation of DB Structure for particular Excel Sheet formats

Tags: sql, database

I have basic knowledge of SQL queries.

Problem Statement:

Every month I will get an Excel sheet with transaction name as one column and the rest of n columns will be dates. The number of rows(Transaction names) are fixed but the dates of a month might vary. I have also attached the screenshot of the excel file.

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu6tJ.jpg)

How should I create a table and structure it in the DB?

How should I import this particular excel table with values in the SQL DB?

Kindly please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Which SQL db? Do you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: You are asking about how to design a database and then how to import data.  That is pretty broad for a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table like this format.

```
Create table table_name(Transaction varchar(40),dates date,values float)
```

This Table looks like:

Transaction   |  dates  | values

billing_ 1    |  11-oct-2019 | 1.2006

billing_ 1    |  12-oct-2019 | 2.2006

billing_ 2    |  11-oct-2019 | 1.2006

billing_ 2    |  12-oct-2019 | 2.2006

For importing excel data.
  First you need to format this type then you can easily import  into the database.